# How do I find lines in a file without exactly 35 occurrences of a character?

Tags: regex, linux, search, ubuntu, sed

How could I use `sed` to find all lines that don't have exactly 35 occurrences of the "|" character?

If I can't use `sed`, what could I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `awk` as it's more readable and doesn't involve nasty regular expression syntax:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF != 36' filename
```

Or `grep`:

```
grep -v '^\([^|]*|\)\{35\}[^|]*$' filename
```

But if you want to use `sed`:

```
sed '/^\([^|]*|\)\{35\}[^|]*$/d' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could try:

```
perl -ne 'print unless (split(/|/, $_)==36);' your_input_file
```

Splits each line at `|` and counts the number of resulting parts. If there are 36, you've got 35 `|` and the line is not printed. Otherwise, the line is printed.